# Execute a batch on a remote computer with C# and show it on screen

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, execute

When I start a batch on a remote computer using this code it runs perfectly. Only problem is, that the called script is not shown on screen. I would like to let the user know, that a program is running. And may read what is done by the used batch.

```
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
options.Username = "user";
options.Password = "password";
options.EnablePrivileges = true;

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope($"{\\remotecomputer}\\root\\CIMV2", options);
scope.Connect();

ObjectGetOptions objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();
ManagementPath managementPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Process");
ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass(scope, managementPath, objectGetOptions);

ManagementBaseObject inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
inParams["CommandLine"] = "cmd /c e:\\tools\\batch.bat >> " + remoteOut + " 2>&1";

ManagementBaseObject outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
```

as said it works great and generates the file "remoteOut" but the user does not see the batch running. Is there an possibility to set the "display" like on linux? I don't want to use ps command.

It runs the code, but the batch is not seen on screen.

Comment: who exactly is "the user"? Chances are you have multiple ones, or non at all.

Comment: the user is unique and in principle the call is working. The same time the call is done the very user is also logged in.  So user "hans" is logged in as the call from remote comes as "hans" to execute a batch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't** - at least, not using WMI directly.

[MS's documentation for `Win32_Process.Create()` states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/create-method-in-class-win32-process#:%7E:text=For%20security%20reasons%20the%20Win32_Process.Create%20method%20cannot%20be%20used%20to%20start%20an%20interactive%20process%20remotely.):

> For security reasons the `Win32_Process.Create` method cannot be used to start an interactive process remotely.

---

There are workarounds, however - [`PsExec` supports starting a process in an interactive session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec#:%7E:text=Run%20the%20program%20so%20that%20it%20interacts%20with%20the%20desktop%20of%20the%20specified%20session) with the `-i [session]` command-line flag.

You can start `PsExec` the usual way with `ProcessStartInfo`.